# ¿Cómo traducir aplicación Universal de Windows10 (UWP) usando XAML?

Tags: xaml, uwp

No consigo poder implementar traducción en las (UWP) aplicaciones universales de windows10.

He creado una carpeta y creado el archivo de recurso .resw, con las siguiente estructura **Resources/es-ES/Resources.resw** dentro de Resources.resw solo tengo *String1* con el valor "Hola Mundo" y en la plantilla XAML indico la carga del recurso con **x:Uid**  `<TextBlock x:Uid="String1" text="hi" />`
Pero cuando compilo el texto muestra *hi*, que es el especificado inicialmente, como puedo que se muestre *Hola Mundo*, el idioma del dispositivo ya está especificado en español de España, es decir que use "es-ES"

Comment: ¿Podría ser una problema por cómo se carga el fichero resw en el código?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, acabo de poderlo solucionar, el error es que pensaba que funcionaba como los recursos de Android y no, en el identificador se debe especificar la propiedad que será remplazada con el valor, después de '.'

Comment: Genial. Deberías agregar eso como respuesta a la pregunta y así, si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema, puede encontrar una solución aquí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solucionado!**

La traducción de recursos en las aplicaciones universales de windows10 las (UWP), en el identificador del recurso de traducción además de especificar un identificador se debe especificar a que propiedad afectará, es decir si el destinatario és un `textblock` para cambiar el texto se requiere modificar la propiedad `text`, por lo cual dentro de `Resources.resw` `idRecurso.Text` y el valor a remplazar.

**Resources.resw**

```
helloWorld.Text => Hola mundo
```

En el layout XAML se debe especificar la relación con el recurso con `x:Uid`:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="helloWorld" />
```